# Referral Linking is NOT working for the Installed application, but working fine for uninstalled application

Tags: android, referrer

I have to implement referral linking concept in my application for it, I have done some code for it. It works fine, when the application is NOT installed on my device. Means I am getting referral.

But the **PROBLEM** is that, I am not getting any referral when application is already installed in my device.

Here is my code which I have used to get referral.

In `Manifest` file.

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.tv.testing.utils.InstallReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In my **Java** class

```
package com.tv.testing.utils;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tv.testing.BuildConfig;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String rawReferrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        System.out.println("Here is the REFFEREAL  first works for us====>>"+rawReferrer);

        if (rawReferrer != null) {
            trackReferrerAttributes(rawReferrer, context);
        }
    }

    private void trackReferrerAttributes(String rawReferrer, Context context) {
        String referrer = "";

        try {

            referrer = URLDecoder.decode(rawReferrer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Here is the REFFEREAL SECOND works for us====>>"+referrer);

        Toast.makeText(context ,"Install reference ==>> "+referrer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Is there any other way to get referral when the application is already installed on my device?

Comment: The referral is only used to track installs. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here: tracking updates?

Comment: @SimonMarquis ...sir...actually i want to get the referral from the link like sms or mail..Either application is installed on my device or not....Yet now i getting the referral only when the application is not installed on my device.

Comment: Because when the app is already installed, referral link has no sense. It's rather the deeplink mechanism you should use. Lots of documentation on d.android.com about this.

Comment: Sir please help me... i am searching lots of link...but i am not get proper solution...

Comment: please see my screen shot http://postimg.org/image/mtlji9lkh/     ..... First option in my image is my application... Second link for Google play,,,,and last is my browser... I am getting the data on clicking only on the First option.......While on clicking on the google play...it show me two option open Or unistalled...While i click on the open option...it does not give me refferal or data.......................Please help me sir

Comment: It's because when you launch your app, referral is no longer used this way. Instead, you must get it from within your activity's `onCreate()` with  `intent.getData()`.